# Is there any view in SystemUI

Tags: android, user-interface, system, launcher, android-launcher

I want to know the working of `SystemUI`.
I have a class which extends `SystemUI`.

- Is there any view in `SystemUI`?
- if yes, what is that and how it works?
- if no, Why and how the view part is done?

Thanks in Advance!!